# Updating Windows with a key press

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When you are on a webpage, you can press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key and the page will update.

When you have the Windows Update program open, you have to click on *Check for updates* to make Windows check for updates.

Is there a key, or combination of keys, I can press while in Windows Update that will make it check for updates without me having to click the *Check for updates* link?

Comment: To improve your question show some research effort by [edit]ing your question to include what have you researched or tried already.

Comment: I take it just hitting enter doesn't work, or tab until the check for updates is selected and then enter?

Comment: @BobVale Tab and Enter does work but I have to hit tab 6 times to get the correct selection to press enter. I didn't know if there was just one key I could press instead.

Comment: I'm sat on windows 8 at the moment so can't look, I take it `alt` doesn't underline a letter on the button telling you which key to press.  ie pressing `alt` underlines `u` telling you that `alt` + `u` will press the button

Comment: Although on my windows 2008r2 box which should be equivalent its one tab

Comment: Also you could manually run `wuauclt /detectnow` to force an update check in the background?

Comment: When you open the Windows Update window directly via the keyboard (by searching for "Windows Update", arrowing to it in the list and hitting enter), focus is on the "Control Panel Home" link, so you can just hit down once and then hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180265/automatically-update-windows-fully), Its Batch programming. Which means you would just need to run the .BAT file and it would do as you wished. If you want it bound to a key you can use [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and bind the .BAT file to a **shift+U** or what ever you want combo. That first link however will show you how to make it run at startup. Which i think is better than smashing a button.